# Magento sessions expiring too soon

Tags: magento, session, cookies

i can't get the Magento sessions correct. I want the admin session and customer cookies to last at least 24hrs. Now they expire in about 10min. Also, for customers, by then the carts are emptied.

I did set the value for the cookie in `configuration/web/` and for the admin in `configuration/advanced/admin` to 86400. I also put this in the `.htaccess`:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400 
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
```

Still, all sessions expire after about 10min.

What setting did I forget?

Comment: Can you check your 'cookie domain' settings under:Under System > Configuration > Web ?

Comment: people, please read! I already said that i did put 86400 there.

Answer (score 0):

There's an menu item for this in:

**System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (Seconds)**

Also check the php environment variables

- php_value session.cookie_lifetime `<seconds>`
- php_value session.gc_maxlifetime `<seconds>`

In order to ensure that you are editing the correct php.ini, create a simple "check.php" file with the following content:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

, place the file in your magento home directory, call it from your browser  (URL/check.php) and check these settings.

For more informations look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

---

[image]

Also set "Session Lifetime (seconds)" under `System > Configuration > Admin` to a high value like **7200** so you don't need to login repeatedly

Comment: Hi Josua, thank you for your answer, but as you could have read in my question, i already did do all these things.

Comment: There is no such path System > Configuration

Comment: @Joti Hi, it's on Magento v1xx btw